# Can't set attribute on result objects in SQLAlchemy flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I encounter a problem with Flask-SQLAlchemy, I can set the attribute of the objects in **place_collections**, but when I want to set the attribute for objects in **places**, an error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/fixers.py", line 152, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/user/Document/Python/Test/Code/app/main/views.py", line 108, in index
    place.distance = round(distance_computing, 1)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

How can I set the attribute for join search object, could anyone help me?

```
place_collections = Place.query.filter_by(county='BKK')

places = db.session.query(Place.roll_number, Place.name, Place.website, Place.address, Place.distance)
            .outerjoin(Rank, Rank.place_id == Place.place_id)
```

Both of them are **class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'** type.

---

```
for place in place_collections:
       distance_computing = Place.distance_calculator(float(place.lat), float(place.lng),
                                                            data['lat'], data['lng'])

       place.distance = round(distance_computing, 1)
```

---

```
for place in places:
       distance_computing = Place.distance_calculator(float(school.lat), float(school.lng),
                                                            data['lat'], data['lng'])

       place.distance = round(distance_computing, 1)
```

**Model**

```
class Rank(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'rank'
    place_id = db.Column(db.String(50))
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    rank = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Place(db.Model):
    _tablename_ = 'school'
    place_id = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
    roll_number = db.Column(db.String(50))
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255))
    distance = db.Column(db.String(50))
    rank = db.relationship('Rank',backref=db.backref('roll_number1'), lazy=True, uselist=False)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`place_collections = Place.query.filter_by(county='BKK')` will return you a collection of `Place` objects. This is analogous to `session.query(Place).filter_by(county='BKK')` in plain vanilla SQLAlchemy.

However, from the SQLAlchemy [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying):

> The Query also accepts ORM-instrumented descriptors as arguments. Any
>   time multiple class entities or column-based entities are expressed as
>   arguments to the query() function, the return result is expressed as
>   tuples

The key point being that when you specify specific columns to query as you have done here:

```
places = db.session.query(Place.roll_number, Place.name,
    Place.website, Place.address, Place.distance).\
    outerjoin(Rank, Rank.place_id == Place.place_id)
```

the result is expressed as a collection of `tuples`.

My first impression was that `can't set attribute` was a strange error message to receive from trying to assign an attribute value to a `tuple`, so I tried it:

```
>>> t = tuple()
>>> t.attribute = 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'attribute'
```

That's not the error message that you received.

So I performed a query similar to your second one (the model is just something from a project that I had open):

```
>>> q = session.query(Racecard.id, Racecard.meeting)
>>> a_result = q[0]
>>> type(a_result)
<class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>
```

Right, so we aren't getting a tuple, we get a `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result` object. But..

```
>>> issubclass(type(a_result), tuple)
True
```

So, the `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result` *is* a *type* of `tuple`.

If we try to assign a value to an attribute that is not one of the columns that were queried:

```
>>> a_result.newattribute = 'something'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'newattribute'
```

That error message is very similar to the one that we got before when assigning an attribute to a plain `tuple`.

So why did you get a different error message? The `result` object is actually more like a `namedtuple`:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Racecard = namedtuple('Racecard', 'id, meeting')
>>> rc = Racecard(1, 'Doomben')
>>> rc.meeting = 'Eagle Farm'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Which is the same error message that you are getting.

So, the `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result` object supports attribute access of the column names, but as it is a `tuple` it is still immutable, so you cannot write to those attributes.

To fix your specific error (unless there was some reason that you were specifically querying only those columns) change your `places` query to:

```
places = db.session.query(Place).outerjoin(Rank, Rank.place_id == Place.place_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause for this error ("AttributeError: can't set attribute" error) is when you have both a column and a property with an identical name.

It happened to me with an `@property` that I had previously added (and forgotten about), then created a column with the same name.