# How can I set attribute to specific columns from SQLAlchemy results?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using python-flask, sqlalchemy.
I had a problem about sqlalchemy results.
I want specific column results from my table so I tried this

```
query = session.query(Table.column_one, Table.coulmn_two).first()
```

so I had results, but I can't update that results.
I tried like this

```
query.column_one = value
```

or

```
setattr(query, column_one, value)
```

but the results is:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

so I found this post
[Can't set attribute on result objects in SQLAlchemy flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391039/cant-set-attribute-on-result-objects-in-sqlalchemy-flask)
and in this post, there is no way to set attribute from that query.
Is this real? Is there no way?

Comment: How did you print the result?

Comment: i just print (query), so the result is like that : (column_one, column_two)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many methods!

**Method #1:**

You have to get the whole object to update it

Try this:

```
query = session.query(Table).first()
query.column_one = value # setattr(query, column_one, value)
session.commit()
```

**Method #2:**

Using SQLAlchemy Core API

```
from sqlalchemy import update

stmt = update(Table).where(Table.c.id==5).values(id=1)
```

More information about this method on [this link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html?highlight=update#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update)

> There are other methods, mentioned by [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4) in the
>   [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619891/how-can-i-set-attribute-to-specific-columns-from-sqlalchemy-results/52620963?noredirect=1#comment92177173_52620963) , So the credit goes to him, upvote his comment!

**Method #3:**

`load_only()` method, It can get used like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_only

query = session.query(Table).options(load_only("column_one", "column_two"))
query.column_one = Value
session.commit()
```

More information about `load_only()` method on this [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#load-only-cols)

**Method #4:**

`Query.update()`

```
session.query(Table).filter(Table.column_one == 25).update({Table.column_one: 10}, synchronize_session=False)
session.commit()
```

More information about `Query.update()` [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update)!

Comment: thanks answer but i had a performance issue.
The whole query like query(table) is too slow(because my table has lots of column...) so i just want to modify some specific column

Comment: I'll update the answer, there is a Core API that let u update without selecting and loading the whole object

Comment: @KimJangHun Updated.

Comment: @KimJangHun, if the answer is useful, upvote it. If the answer is complete, accept it.

Comment: Just as a side note: `load_only()` is also an option, if trying to avoid loading wide tables. There's also `Query.update()`, if one wants to use the session instead of Core.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Interesting, Can u share a link on docs about it?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html and https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update.

Comment: @IljaEverilä load_only is awsome... i appreciate it.. T_T thanks, thanks..