# SQLAlchemy can't set attribute error when updating value

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table `mailtable` in a backend PostgreSQL database and I'm querying it using SQLAlchemy ORM using a given `mailId`. For the following code, the `amEngine` is already set up. When it gets to the `mailRow.usercomment = 'Hello World'` line, it throws:

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

```
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(amEngine)
metaAm = MetaData()
metaAm.reflect(bind=amEngine)
mt = metaAm.tables['mailtable']
Session = sessionmaker(bind=amEngine)
amSession = Session()
mailRow = amSession.query(
        mt
    ).filter(
        mt.c.id == mailId
    ).first()
mailAddress = mailRow.address
mailRow.usercomment = 'Hello World'
amSession.flush()
amSession.commit()
```

I need to read the `address` column (successful) and update the `usercomment` column (throws exception). The PostgreSQL type for both columns is `text`.
How can I do this? I'm sure this must be a very simple issue, but for the life of me I cannot see the problem.

Many thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391039/cant-set-attribute-on-result-objects-in-sqlalchemy-flask/51397734#51397734

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By calling `MetaData.reflect` you asked SQLAlchemy to autodetect the `Table` objects, describing your database. You may use these objects to create language-agnostic SQL queries, such as

```
engine.execute(update(mt).where(mt.c.id==1).values(usercomment='Hello World'))
```

You cannot yet use the `Table` objects to do proper ORM, however. When you query a `Table` object (via `session.query(mt)`) you will get the results returned to you as read-only `namedtuple`-like objects. Setting their attributes makes no sense, hence you observe the exception.

To enjoy actual ORM, you need to create the corresponding ORM classes and map them to the `Table` objects.

Of course, you can ask SQLAlchemy to auto-reflect the ORM classes for you together with the tables using [automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html). Here is the code you probably wanted to write:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Ask SQLAlchemy to reflect the tables and 
# create the corresponding ORM classes:
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(amEngine, reflect=True)

# This is the ORM class we are interested in:
MailTable = Base.classes.mailtable

# Create the session, query, update and commit:
Session = sessionmaker(bind=amEngine)
session = Session()
mailRow = session.query(MailTable).get(mailId)
mailAddress = mailRow.address
mailRow.usercomment = 'Hello World'
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 4):

You are querying a `Table` object directly, not via an instrumented model:

```
mt = metaAm.tables['mailtable']
print(type(mt))
# <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>
```

When you query a table, you are returned an instance of `<class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>` which is a type of `namedtuple`. Tuples are immutable, so you cannot change the value of its attributes.